# How to replace "*" into all columns when writing SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, intellij-idea, navicat

It is a bad habbit to use select "*" when writing SQL with JDBC.

But what if there are many columns in the table(s), how can I easily pickup some wanted columns in the SQL rather than using `*`?

For example,suppose I have table1 and table2,which have 10 columns each. I need most of their columns, but I do not want to use `SELECT * FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id` since this is a bad practice. Actually I only need `SELECT column1,column4,column5(most of them)...... from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id`.

So, do I have a way that replace `*` into all columns and then I can just COPY this text and remove some columns which I don't need and remain what I want rather than type each column name?

Comment: This is usually something that your SQL client does for your.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what about navicat?

Comment: No idea, I don't use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, an easy trick is to open a database in Management Studio, right-click on a table and select "Select top 1000 Rows" from the context menu.  You'll get all the fields listed one by one.  You can copy and paste the text wherever you want.

I don't know which IDE you're using let alone which DBMS, but there's probably a trick like this one in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the query below which is use to get all the columns of a specific table. Hope it helps you.

```
SELECT name FROM sys.all_columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTableHere')
```

In MySQL, try the code below or you can refer in this [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM MyTableNameHere;
```